# Detect an idle asyncio event loop

Tags: python-asyncio

Is there some programming pattern that would enable me to detect when an asyncio event loop becomes idle in the following sense? Say that my  execution path branches in some complex way, say, using asyncio.gather(), but I know that each branch eventually awaits some idle coroutine, such as a socket or a subprocess. Say I know these coroutines actually never yield, so the event loop will execute whatever python code it can but eventually will just wait for those idle coroutines. Is there a programmatic way to detect such a state and stop the loop?

Comment: Why do you need to stop loop? If it stops before socket or subprocess jobs completed it wouldn't be able to propagate results to coroutines waiting for it.

Comment: Those never-yielding coroutines have side effects, which I want to be executed. But once all of them are executed, I want the application to stop. This is a particular use-case scenario of the app, in which the execution path is simply interrupted.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code which contains these coroutines that never yiled and you want to detect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Philip Couling, the solution presented below **doesn't work**. StackOverflow doesn't allow deleting an accepted answer, so I am adding this disclaimer.

---

What you call "idle" might be more accurately described as "waiting for IO or a timeout". In correctly written asyncio code one shouldn't need to detect that the loop is in that state because it shouldn't *matter* - the loop is doing its job, and it is up to the tools like `asyncio.gather`, `asyncio.wait`, and `loop.run_until_complete` to ensure that it ends at the appropriate time. However, things are not always perfect, and if you really want to do that, it is certainly possible.

At each step of the event loop it checks for tasks that are ready to run. If there are any, their steps are invoked. Once no more tasks are ready, the event loop waits for an IO event or the soonest timeout, whichever happens first. The important thing to notice is that running tasks always have precedence over waiting for IO. Therefore, to detect the case when no tasks are ready, one can schedule a dummy IO event that is known to fire immediately.

The following coroutine sets up such an event and awaits it to trigger:

```py
import socket, asyncio

async def detect_iowait():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    rsock, wsock = socket.socketpair()
    wsock.close()
    await loop.sock_recv(rsock, 1)
    rsock.close()
```

It sets up a [socket pair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) where reading from one socket returns the data written into the other socket. It immediately closes one of the sockets, so that reading from the other one immediately returns EOF, represented as an empty bytearray. Awaiting a read from that socket is fundamentally non-blocking - but `asyncio` doesn't know that, so it places the socket among on the IO wait list. As noted above, as soon as no runnable tasks are present, asyncio will wait for IO and `detect_iowait` will await the read on the socket and exit. Thus awaiting `detect_iowait()` itself detects IO wait.

Test code that uses `detect_iowait()` might look like this:

```py
# stop loop.run_forever once iowait is detected
async def stop_on_iowait():
    await detect_iowait()
    print('iowait detected, stopping!')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

# a dummy calculation coroutine, emulating your execution path
async def calc(n):
    print('calc %d start' % n)
    async def noop():
        pass
    for i in range(n):
        await noop()
    print('calc %d end' % n)

# coroutine that waits on IO forever, also (ab)using a socket pair,
# this time creating a socket whose recv will never complete
async def io_forever():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    sock, _ = socket.socketpair()
    sock.setblocking(False)
    await loop.sock_recv(sock, 1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for t in calc(1000), calc(10000), calc(100000), io_forever():
    loop.create_task(t)
loop.create_task(stop_on_iowait())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: This doesn't work at least in python 3.8. The example code here doesn't actually test for the event loop being idle. The reason being that test code never suspends at all. [`await noop()` is not sufficient to suspend the task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998823/453851). When I ran this with tasks that actually suspended (python 3.8) it didn't work. I've posted a follow up question here with example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732618/is-it-possible-to-detect-when-all-async-tasks-are-suspended